# Identify redundant GCP resources created by Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

When creating various Kubernetes objects in GKE, associated GCP resources are automatically created. I'm specifically referring to:

- `forwarding-rules`
- `target-http-proxies`
- `url-maps`
- `backend-services`
- `health-checks`

These have names such as `k8s-fw-service-name-tls-ingress--8473ea5ff858586b`.

After deleting a cluster, these resources remain. How can I identify which of these are still in use (by other Kubernetes objects, or another cluster) and which are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to identify which added GCP resources (LB, backend, etc.) are linked to which cluster. You need to manually go into these resources to see what they are linked to.

If you delete a cluster with additional resources attached, you have to also manually delete these resources as well. At this time, I would suggest taking note of which added GCP resources are related to which cluster, so that you will know which resources to delete when the time comes to deleting the GKE cluster.

I would also suggest to create a feature request [here](http://issuetracker.google.com) to request for either a more defined naming convention for additional GCP resources being created linked to a specific cluster and/or having the ability to automatically delete all additonal resources linked to a cluster when deleting said cluster.

Comment: Yes, I think the most useful advice for now is: don't delete a cluster without deleting your kubernetes resources first, else you're in for a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to look at https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/14-cleanup.md

You can easily delete all the objects by using the google cloud sdk in the following manner :

```
gcloud -q compute firewall-rules delete \
kubernetes-the-hard-way-allow-nginx-service \
kubernetes-the-hard-way-allow-internal \
kubernetes-the-hard-way-allow-external \
kubernetes-the-hard-way-allow-health-check

{
  gcloud -q compute routes delete \
  kubernetes-route-10-200-0-0-24 \
  kubernetes-route-10-200-1-0-24 \
  kubernetes-route-10-200-2-0-24

  gcloud -q compute networks subnets delete kubernetes

  gcloud -q compute networks delete kubernetes-the-hard-way

  gcloud -q compute forwarding-rules delete kubernetes-forwarding-rule \
  --region $(gcloud config get-value compute/region)

  gcloud -q compute target-pools delete kubernetes-target-pool

  gcloud -q compute http-health-checks delete kubernetes

  gcloud -q compute addresses delete kubernetes-the-hard-way
}
```

This assumes you named your resources 'kubernetes-the-hard-way', if you do not know the names, you can also use various filter mechanisms to filter resources by namespaces etc to remove these.

Comment: Hi Dhruva, thanks for your response. This does suggest I could better name all of my resources. They have names like "k8s-fw-service-name-tls-ingress--8473ea5ff858586b". Presumably I could replace "8473ea5ff858586b" with my own string so I could better identify my resources? At the end of your answer you've alluded to (but not answered) the part of my question which is most important to me: I don't know the names; I can't efficiently identify clusters that no longer exist, collect their unused resources and delete them.

Comment: I've read a little more of your link and it looks like the author manually creates and names resources. I'm not doing this; they're automatically created and named when the Kubernetes objects are created.

Comment: Yes like I mentioned in my answer (added in an edit), that is the case, if you did not do that, you should still be able to restrict all the gcloud calls by adding an additional namespace / label filter as applicable and achieve what you need

Comment: It doesn't look as though you've edited your answer. I'm afraid I'm still at a loss as to how to identify whether the resources are actually in use or not. Could you perhaps provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: For the record, I've looked through output from `gcloud compute forwarding-rules list --format=json | vim +'set ft=json' -` and similar for each of the different resource types, and can't see anything there.

Comment: you could try with things like `--all-namespaces` but it is possible you did delete them successfully

Comment: perhaps it may serve you better to cross check the same over google's cloud dashboard itself